# Beautiful Soup - Get all elements

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

Newbie with Beautiful Soup would appreciate any pointers.

I'm working with a page which has a lot of:

```
<p data-v-04dd08f2> .. </p>
```

elements. Inside the p is a string value, which I need and an embedded span.

Question might be very simple... I am trying to use find_all to 'get' a list of all those elements which I would subsequently parse out to get the tokens I need from inside.

Can someone put me out my misery and tell me how the find_all should be structured to get these?

I've tried:

```
find_all('p',{'data':'v-04dd08f2'} } # nope
find_all('p', {"attributes': 'v-04dd08f2'} ) # nope
```

and lots of other combinations all to no avail.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to use CSS selectors instead, which I personally prefer to BeautifulSoup's find_* methods and the paragraph tags are in fact exactly what you indicated, that "data-v-04dd08f2" is an attribute of the tag, then the following should do the trick

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup('<p data-v-04dd08f2> .. </p>')
p_tags = soup.select('p[data-v-04dd08f2]')
print(p_tags)
#[<p data-v-04dd08f2=""> .. </p>]
```

bs4 uses SoupSieve to implement CSS selectors. The SoupSieve docs for selecting based on attribute are [here](https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/selectors/basic/#attribute-selectors). Note that based on your attempts I suspect you might actually be looking for p tags who have a data attribute = 'v-04dd08f2'. If that's the case the `soup.select` string should be `soup.select('p[data=v-04dd08f2]')`

Answer (score 1):

This will return all elements having attribute name starting with *"data-v-"*

```
match_pattern = 'data-v-'
m = soup.findAll(lambda tag: any(attr.startswith(match_pattern) for attr in tag.attrs.keys()))
```

`element.attrs` is a key-value structure, {attribute_name: attribute_value}